# Explanation on overriding variables java inheritance

Tags: java, polymorphism

Can someone explain why the function prints the variable from super and not from the subclass? Class variables cannot be overridden in Java?

```
 class A {
  int i = 1;
  int fun() {
   return i;
  }
 }

 class B extends A {
  int i = 2;
 }

class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(new B().fun());
 }
}
```

This prints out `1` instead of `2`.

Comment: You can only override methods, not fields.

Comment: becuase `fun()` is extended from A to B and you are calling fun method which has the value 1 . And fields can not be override only methods can

Comment: You mean 'override', not 'overwrite', and there is no such thing as overriding variables in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because fields declared in the subclass never override fields of the super class.

Overriding is for methods.
If you want to use the `i` value of the current class, you could introduce `getI()` a method to provide the `i` value :

```
 class A {
  int i = 1;
  int fun() {
   return getI();
  }
  int getI(){
    return i;
  }
 }
```

And override it in the subclass :

```
 class B extends A {
  int i = 2;

  int getI(){
    return i;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the value of `i` from `fun()` function . if you want to return the value of override variable from class `B` need to override that method, as `fun` method is a part of the super class  it is referring `i` of super class only.

But always remember overriding of variable in java is always a bad idea it may give you unexpected result.

if you still want you can use this way.

```
class A {
  int i = 1;
  int fun() {
   return i;
  }
 }

 class B extends A {
  int i = 2;
  int fun() {
       return i;
      }
 }
 class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.out.println(new B().fun()); // this will refer the override i 
}
}
```